# How do I type the react useState hook?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, interface

I have a problem with typing 2 elements in my React components.

First one:

```
 const [data, setData] = useState<any>(localRead);
```

I'm using it to get localStorage and using to keep my data from APIs

second one is:

```
 const [response, setResponse] = useState<any>([]);
```

this one works just like getting information from API and using interfaces Vimeo + YouTube + Video, but when I'm using it, it does not want to work..

Any ideas on how could I type it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first example, if you omit the `<any>` then typescript will infer the type of `localRead` as the type of the state:

```
const [data, setData] = useState(localRead);
// data is now the same type as localRead
```

---

But the second example is harder. You have to provide a type hint to `useState` since its value is set later. To figure out what type to use, you have to use the return type of the function that provides this data. In most typescript environments you can hover your cursor over the function that see what type it returns. That's the type you want to provide to `useState`.

For instance, lets say you were using a library that was implemented like this:

```
// External library that provides data.
export type MyData = { foo: number }[]

export function getMyData(): MyData {
    return [
        { foo: 123 },
        { foo: 456 },
    ]
}
```

Then you could write a component that looked like:

```
function Component() {
    const [myState, setMyState] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        const myData = getMyData()
        setMyState(myData)
    }, [])

    return <></>
}
```

At this point the type of `myState` is wrong. But if you hover over `getMyData`, you should see the type information, which would look like:

```
function getMyData(): MyData
```

You can now `import { MyData } from 'whatever-lib'` and use that for your state. Resulting in:

```
function Component() {
    const [myState, setMyState] = useState<MyData>([])

    useEffect(() => {
        const myData = getMyData()
        setMyState(myData)
    }, [])

    return <></>
}
```

Of course, depending on what libraries you are using those types may be different, but this describes how you might go about discovering the right type from your state, when that state comes from other code.

[Playground with the above example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=26&ssc=2&pln=16&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgKIBmZSG2RSAyjCjEnAL5xlQQhwDkUqDLwBQo4QHpxcEgA9mUAHYoANnGXAARlBRQAnnBgALJnDBcAbsAAmSQnCtMUAOmFIZkWAd1gWAWV0AIo5wALy4HBAQAFxwCvggGkhQbADaALqibh7wZPgKGMAQCnAA5kgw-kGMABQAlDGVwTjCcK1wAjD4inApLW39eGSRMQCMAEwAzGyYff2tg8NwACwArABs07NwGaxiknD+cGjckApICjDCufkwhcUAwidF5zB1uFvHCoTwKSC6DEwkNhiBV-oxmGlQgRiADmAAeRqMAB81XStVE-Vo5EoGGqbxCSPeczan2+cD+VRQULKoMpdS2-RB-lhSGqFMc6P6rGwaIxbQ6XWKcKRcPESOErCAA)

---

You could also get the return type from the data function directly with something like:

```
useState<ReturnType<typeof getMyData>>([])
```

This might be handy if the library you are using doesn't export the type that the function returns, or if that type is incredibly verbose in some way. But I would only encourage use of this hard to read type if the above process doesn't yield satisfactory results.